# What is the math font being used in these notes?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

This set of [Physics notes](https://conf.itp.phys.ethz.ch/esi-school/Lecture_notes/WZW%20models.pdf) seems to employ the standard LaTeX math font. However, in Eq. (2.29) the calligraphic D looks like the one from the eulervm package instead of the standard one:

[image]

What math font is this? If it is the standard math font how does one get this calligraphic D instead of the standard one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a mixture of standard `\mathcal` and Euler Script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

\begin{document}

\[
\langle\mathcal{O}\rangle=\int\mathscr{D}g\mathcal{O}[g]e^{-\mathcal{S}[g]}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Sorry, but I just can't write the Euler constant upright.)